# Jenkins Problem with variables in declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins

`I make stage:`

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'built-in' }
    stages {  
      stage("processing_CadEx") {
        steps {  
         script {
          def BuildTarget = sh(script: "cat /tmp/BuildTargets_202", returnStdout: true)
          echo "BuildTarget = ${BuildTarget}"
          if ( "${BuildTarget}" == "CadEx") {
            "BuildTarget2 = ${BuildTarget}"
          }
        }              
      }
    }  
  }
}

and get output:
[Pipeline] { (proc_CadEx)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ cat /tmp/BuildTargets_202
[Pipeline] echo
BuildTarget = CadEx

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
```

BuildTarget2 is not printed although variable BuildTarget, it seems defined correctly and printed as CadEx

I did a lot of experiments but "if" does not work out as I would like

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within your `if` block. Replace it with:

```
if ("${BuildTarget}" == "CadEx") {
    def BuildTarget2 = "${BuildTarget}"
    echo "BuildTarget2 = ${BuildTarget2}"
}
```

You have put `""` around the entire statement, which is wrong, and you haven't echoed out the value of `BuildTarget2`, which is why you didn't see anything in the console output.

I tested you pipeline out with these two changed and everything else seemed to be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes. It's my fault. But that's not what I'm talking about. "if" in principle does not work out. I simplified "if" ` 
`if ("${BuildTarget}" == "CadEx") { echo "I am here"}`
And "I am here" is not printed

Comment: If you were to do this: `def BuildTarget = "CadEx"` before the if statement (which is what I did to test), the if statement would likely work. Therefore, this is a problem where the value of `BuildTarget` is not actually equal to "CadEx". Refer to terokun's answer below since that is probably in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

See that blank line after

```
BuildTarget = CadEx
```

Means your string has a new line at the end. The string you are comparing to - doesn't. Add a `.trim()`. You also don't need this `"${BuildTarget}"` nonsense, `BuildTarget` is already a string.